# How to solve gradle sync error failed(org/gradle/api/publication/maven/internal/DefaultMavenFactory)

Tags: java, android

I have installed the `custom-swipelistview-master` library.But it gave an error in message `gradle` sync. When I am clicking on this error it automatically open the `build.gradle` file. The error showned in message window is:

> Error:(2, 0)
>   Cause: org/gradle/api/publication/maven/internal/DefaultMavenFactory
>    openFile \Users\user1\AndroidStudioProjects\custom-swipelistview-master\customswipelistview\build.gradle

[image]